# Convert simple Dart code to TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dart

I am trying to set up Hello World, AngularJS 2 app, for the first time.

Here's simple HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
    <script type="application/dart" src="hello.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the dart code:

```
class Hello{

  String message;

  Hello(){
        HttpRequest.getString('/hello')
            .then((String content) {
              Map parsedMap = JSON.decode(content);
              message = parsedMap["Message"];
            });
  }
}

main() {
  reflector.reflectionCapabilities = new ReflectionCapabilities();
  bootstrap(AppComponent);
}
```

Could anybody help me convert this Dart code to TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could anybody help me convert this Dart code to TypeScript?

Tips:

- typescript has no `main`.
- you need to `import` the stuff you need into typescript
- has a different naming convention than dart
- http responses of type `applicaiton/json` are commonly automatically parsed (objectified).

Based on that :

```
import {bootstrap} from "some/angular/module"; 
// Do same for http

class Hello {

  message: string;

  hello() {
        http.getString('/hello')
            .then((content) {
              const message = content;
            });
  }
}


bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

## More

I highly recommend you read a book on TypeScript. I wrote a free one : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Dart2Ts is an highly experimental dart to typescript compiler.
https://www.dart-polymer.com/dart2ts/
https://github.com/polymer-dart/dart2ts